# jquery mouseover find() swap divs

Tags: jquery, html, mouseover, fadein, swap

Im a javascript newbie and would need some help with this simple thing... I want div:last to be shown at mouseover over div:first. They are wrapped in .workpost.

I have several .workpost and only want to trigger the active one...

With the code below the fadeIn flickers.

```
$('.workpost').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('div:last').fadeIn(200);
    $(this).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).find('div:last').fadeOut(200);
     });
});
```

Comment: Your code is on `mouseover` of `.workpost` but your description says you want it on `mouseover` of `div:first`.  Which is correct?

Comment: i have a div:first wrapped in .workpost but maybe the wrapper isnt needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont nest the event handlers:

```
$('.workpost').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('div:last').fadeIn(200);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('div:last').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Accept the answer then, please. This code already adds the event handler on all ".wordposts". You do know  that $(".workpost") is an array with all the DOM elements that match ".workpost", do you?

Comment: Yes I know.. not sure how to explain myself though. Is there a simple way to only trigger the ".workpost" where the mouse actually is over. =)

Comment: Thats what $(this) does. Maybe it would be easier if you make a jsfiddle

Comment: It worked... I hade some conflicts with masonry. Thanks alot!! Newbie bow